# can't seem to add any timeformat to my database

Tags: mysql, jdbc, time

I just can't seem to add any timeformat to my database. I tried different Time formats like java.sql.Time and Timestamp, but both failed.

Here is my code:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sqltrappnins);
Date help2 = new Date(ctmpd.getTimeInMillis());  //ctmpd is a Calendar Object
java.sql.Timestamp tjo = new java.sql.Timestamp(help2.getTime());
pstmt.setTimestamp(1, tjo);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Please include log or output of your failed scenario.

Comment: Try adding a Calendar instance as the third parameter to your setTimestamp() call. For example: Calendar calUTC = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); pstmt.setTimestamp(1, tjo, calUTC);

Comment: Please define "failed". A time or timestamp in a database is just a time value, it has no format, and therefor your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The error says:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from

Comment: The value in my database is has the type Time. I tried what maurice said with both Timestamp and java.sql.Time. I still get the same error message

Comment: @todayihateprogramming - Are you able to load any data into your table from mysql? 
use sandbox;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS testStamp ;
CREATE TABLE testStamp(
        tstamp TIMESTAMP,
        val int
);
INSERT INTO testStamp
 values
  ('2001-10-01 12:34:56', 135),
  ('2015-01-03 08:42:20', 246);
SELECT * FROM testStamp;